# An Page reload problem in ASP .net because of client side validaton

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-validate, reload

I have an aspx page where I have used jquery validator in a different .js file. my code for this file is

```
function checkRequiredInputs(){

$("#frmSaleSubmissionInfo").validate({  
    rules:{
        txtFName:{required: true},
        txtLName:{required: true},
        txtAddress:{required: true},
        txtPhone:{required: true}
    },
    messages:{
        txtFName:"Enter Name",
        txtLName:"Enter Name",
        txtAddress:"Enter Address",
        txtPhone:"Enter Phone Number"
    }
});

$("#txtPhone").keydown(function(event) {
    // Allow only backspace,delete,comma(,),left arrow,right arraow and Tab
    if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 188 
        || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 9){
        // let it happen, don't do anything
    }
    else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode <96 ||event.keyCode > 105) ) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
    }
});

}
```

and the validation code is implemented in the aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        checkRequiredInputs();
}); 

 </script>
```

I have a close button and it's like

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnClose" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ButtonImages/Button_Close_Normal.png"
                    Height="16px" onclick="btnClose_Click" />
```

and its click event is 
    protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("anotherPage.aspx", false);
        }

Now my problem is that whenever I click close button, if the validation fails, i.e. if any of the required field remains empty, its not letting to the go that another page. But if validation does not occur, then, The close button takes me to that another page. My obejct is to make that close button work regardless of any client side validation? What will I do? please help me, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're doing when you click btnClose is: `Response.Redirect("anotherPage.aspx", false);` then why bother with a server side control at all?  I would replace btnClose with:

```
<a href="/anotherPage.aspx"><img src="~/ButtonImages/Button_Close_Normal.png" /></a>
```

This will work regardless

Comment: Thanks for your suggesion,but I cant use a link here, I have to use the button. since the page I am working right now is a child page, and anotherPage is the the parent page, so by closing the child page I have to go back to the parent page. So I need to make that server button workable.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow what you mean.  Is there more server-side stuff happening behind that button than just `Response.Redirect("anotherPage.aspx", false);`?

Comment: No, there is not a line line other than what have I written here.

Comment: So I can't see the problem with using the link - can you at least try it?

Comment: You are Great, At first, I could not understand your problem, now I have followed your instruction, and It's working for me. thank you.

Comment: Excellent, no problem at all :-)